# What does "tight friends" mean?

Tags: slang

I learned what **tight** means, but I don't understand what "tight friends" means.

I searched in Google and I didn't find anything.

Here is an examples:

> We're tight friends.

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tight sense 10

Comment: @Max Yes. I meant it

Comment: Why did you search Google instead of a dictionary? Next time, try [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=tight&ls=a).

Comment: @J.R. Because I don't know many dictionary

Comment: That's the nice thing about OneLook – it will link you to _several_ online dictionaries. Plus, it provides excerpts from on its results page from Macmillan (a very good online dictionary). In this case, it says, "a tight group of people have a close relationship with each other."

Answer (score 2):

It means both are very close friends and share personal things with each other.

Answer (score 2):

**tight** in this context means very close friends - [ref 4.1 in the Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tight)

It occurs in the idiomatic expression **as tight as ticks**, which first appeared around the time of the second world war.

> He and Clayburn were as tight as ticks- *The Broker, John Gresham*

When used about communities or groups of people, you can use also the expressions **tight knit** or **tightly knit**, which are slightly older but more widely used today. They are often used in social studies when talking about social groups.

> Tightly knit communities are effective at controlling local crime [The Oxford handbook of Atheism](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=ds8ZAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT413&dq=%22tightly%20knit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUrpmrk9LOAhVBmBQKHY5mCDs4ChDoAQgwMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tightly%20knit%22&f=false)